# Compiler displays "recursive on all control paths" but the function is equipped with a end case

Tags: c++, recursion

```cpp
#include <iostream>

unsigned short n;
unsigned short i = 2;
unsigned short j = 2;
    
bool detector() {
    return (n % j != 0 && n == ++j) * 1 + (n % i != 0 && n != ++i) * detector();
}
    
int main() {
    std::cout << "enter a number greater than 1\n";
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << (n == 2 || n == 3) * 1 + (n > 3) * detector();

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: I wrote #include<iostream> but stackoverflow removed the <iostream>

Comment: "the function is equipped with an end case" is it? im seeing one expression and its recursive

Comment: A recursive function must have a base case, and the function should call itself recursively so that it tends to move towards the base case. But your program doesn't have a base case.

Comment: It would be better if you can specify what you are expecting at the output?

Comment: Maybe you should explain why you think you have an end case, so that answers can help you most.

Comment: What are you trying to detect()  ?

Comment: It's a program to detect whether a number is prime or not. And I tried my best not to make use of conditional statements. Pardon me as I didn't mention what the program is all about.

Answer (score 2):

It's because there is no base case in your recursive function. The `detector()` function will keep on giving out an infinite value as there is no base case to terminate the recursive call in the `detector()` function.

Answer (score 2):

`detector()` is evaluated regardless of the value of `n % i != 0 && n != ++i` – there is no short-circuiting in multiplication.

Also, since the evaluation order of operands in arithmetic is unspecified, `detector()` might happen before anything else, leaving both `i` and `j` unmodified.

The simplest fix is to use logical operators instead of arithmetic:

```
bool detector() {
    return (n % j != 0 && n == ++j) || (n % i != 0 && n != ++i && detector());
}
```

You should also change `main`, which suffers from the same lack of short-circuiting:

```
std::cout << n == 2 || n == 3 || (n > 3 && detector());
```

I would also rewrite the code to not use global variables.
Globals are bad for you, but globals and recursion is even worse.

Comment: Ya, I did some experimentation based on what you answered. Well, it's helpful. Thank you.